# Como posso interceptar click em link dentro de WebView?

Tags: c#, xamarin

No meu aplicativo Android, tenho uma webview que abre vários sites diferentes.

Tudo funciona nos conformes, porém quando tem um link na página, e o usuário clica nesse link, o navegador é aberto.

Gostaria de saber se existe algum evento de clique nos elementos que estão dentro da webview, ou se existe alguma outra maneira de tratar esses cliques dentro do app.

Minha intenção é abrir tudo dentro da webview, para que o usuário não saia do aplicativo

Comment: Talvez estas perguntas do **SOen** possam te ajudar também: 

[Link should be open in same web view in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308904/link-should-be-open-in-same-web-view-in-android) **/**
[How to load external webpage inside WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305089/how-to-load-external-webpage-inside-webview)

Answer (score 0):

Cria uma classe CustomWebview que herda de Webview e intercepta o click no evento navigating.

Ex:

```
    public class CustomWebView: WebView
    {
        public String Code { get; set; }

        public CustomWebView()
        {
            Navigating += CustomWebView_Navigating;
        }


        private void CustomWebView_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
              //Faz alguma coisa
        }
    }
```

Depois da uma olhada nesse link, talvez te ajude! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38527183/xamarin-forms-handle-hyperlinks-in-webview-navigating-issue